# I am getting error in the verilog code for stopwatch in Altera DE1

Tags: verilog

I am getting error in verilog code while compiling using Quartus II as under

Error (10119): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at DE1_SOC_golden_top.v(313): loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations

Line 313 is      #50 clock = ~clock;

code for the test bench module is

```
module test;

 // Inputs
 reg clock;
 reg reset;
 reg start;

 // Outputs
 wire [3:0] d0;
 wire [3:0] d1;
 wire [3:0] d2;

 // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
 stopwatch uut (
  .clock(clock), 
  .reset(reset), 
  .start(start), 
  .d0(d0), 
  .d1(d1), 
  .d2(d2)
 );

initial
  begin
   clock = 0;
    forever
     #50 clock = ~clock;
  end

 initial begin
  // Initialize Inputs
  reset = 0;
  start = 0;

  // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
  #100;
  reset = 1;
  #100;
  reset = 0;
  #100;
  start = 1;
  // Add stimulus here
 end
```

endmodule

Any suggestions for rectifying the same. I am generating a 0.1 second delay..

Comment: Quartus is synthesis. You typically only simulate with a testbench as they often contain unsynthesizable code (like forever loops).

Comment: ok you mean I should be doing compilation with the original code and only test code for simulation.. right.

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite the line as below to clear the error

```
clock = #50 ~clock;
```

Comment: As the other answer says, the questioner is trying to synthesise a testbench. That is the fundamental problem.

Comment: Really?  Since he didn't mention synthesis specifically, I assumed he was using the QuartusII edition with Modelsim.(This is the development kit right?) The statment, "I am getting error in verilog code" meant that the error was the problem and the root of the question.  Not to mention that he mentioned a desire to resolve this error, "Error (10119): Verilog HDL Loop Statement error at DE1_SOC_golden_top.v(313): loop with non-constant loop condition must terminate within 250 iterations".  Given that it is testbench code, hooking an external clock to it doesn't actually seem relevant does it?

Answer (score 0):

```
initial
  begin
   clock = 0;
    forever
     #50 clock = ~clock;
  end
```

This method of generating a clock only works in simulation workflows. For synthesis, you need to connect an actual clock signal to the FPGA.